# IEnumerator keeps crashing unity when using it to spawn an enemy ever 0.5 seconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, ienumerator

I understand that this usually means there is an infinite loop somewhere, however I have narrowed it down to this IEnumerator since when I remove it, it works fine, but spawns all the enemies at once. The idea is that it works out how many enemies are required for that wave, then spawns 1 enemy per 0.5 seconds unitl that amount is reached, rather than spawning all enemies for the wave at once.

Update Method:

```
void Update()
{
    Enemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("EndlessKnife");
    NoOfEnemies = 0;
    foreach (GameObject Enemy in Enemies)
    {
        NoOfEnemies++;
    }
    if (NoOfEnemies == 0)
    {
        waveNumber++;
        StartingAmount = Mathf.RoundToInt(waveNumber + (Mathf.Pow(1.2f, waveNumber)));
        for (int i = 0; i < StartingAmount;)
        {
            if (Limit == false)
            {
                SpawnEnemy();
                i++;
                Limit = true;
                StartCoroutine(GradualSpawn());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

IEnumerator:

```
IEnumerator GradualSpawn()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        Limit = false;
    }
```

I use this same logic for limiting rate of fire for my weapons so do not understand why it is crashing here, any input is helpful :D

Comment: Can you add the stack trace? Might be helpful in pinpointing where the issue is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your getting stuck here `if (Limit == false)`. You'll want to restructure your code a little so it's that all the waiting and looping happens in your coroutine, or your program will block.

```
if (NoOfEnemies == 0){
    waveNumber++;
    StartingAmount = Mathf.RoundToInt(waveNumber + (Mathf.Pow(1.2f, waveNumber)));
    StartCoroutine(GradualSpawn(StartingAmount));
}
```

Then in your coroutine

```
IEnumerator GradualSpawn(int StartingAmount)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < StartingAmount; i++){
        SpawnEnemy();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    }
}
```

This should spawn one enemy every 0.5 seconds.
Hope this helps

Comment: I just want to add that your method works just as well so thank you for your input :D

Answer (score 3):

A for loop will mean that you want all your enemies to be spawned on the same frame (which you don't) because a for loop will keep executing whilst the int i is smaller than your StartingAmount. If you want to spawn enemies over a period of time, just use an if statement instead of a for loop:

```
int i = 0;
if (i < StartingAmount) {
    if (Limit == false) {
         SpawnEnemy();
         i++;
         Limit = true;
         StartCoroutine(GradualSpawn());
    }
}
```

This should work now :)

Comment: I can confirm this has worked, such a simple solution I should have realised, thank you very much :D

Comment: Does this not cause one enemy to be spawned per frame (after a 0.5 second pause), or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @Jake it spawns an enemy once every x seconds up until the amount required for that wave

Comment: oh i see, the `Limit` is a flag